# AngularJS ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, events, select-menu

i have this select script, and I want to close the menu when

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
        zc-select {
            width: 200px;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }
            
        zc-select > .select-head {
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
            
        zc-select > .select-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            max-height: 200px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
            
        zc-select > .select-content li {
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        zc-select > .select-content li:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);    
        }
        </style>
  <script>
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
            
        app.run(function () {
            angular.element.prototype.has = function(selector) {
                if ( ! this.length || typeof this === 'undefined' ) return false;
                if ( ! selector.length || typeof selector === 'undefined' ) return false;

                if ( typeof selector === 'object' ) {
                    
                    var selector_query = selector[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
                    if ( selector[0].id.length ) {
                        selector_query += "#" + selector[0].id;
                    }                
                    if ( selector[0].className.length ) {
                        selector[0].className.split(" ").forEach(function(i) {
                            selector_query += "." + i;
                        });
                    }
                    
                    var el = this[0].querySelector(selector_query);
                    if ( el ) {
                        if ( el === selector [ 0 ] ) {
                            return angular.element(el);   
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ( typeof selector === 'string' ) {
                    var els = this[0].querySelectorAll(selector);
                    for ( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
                        if ( els [ i ] === selector [ i ] ) {
                            return angular.element(els[i]);   
                        }
                    }               
                }
            }; 
        });    
        app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.countries = [
                {id: 1, name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
                {id: 2, name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'},
                {id: 3, name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'},
                {id: 4, name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'},
                {id: 5, name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'},
                {id: 6, name: 'Andorra', code: 'AD'},
                {id: 7, name: 'Angola', code: 'AO'},
                {id: 8, name: 'Anguilla', code: 'AI'},
                {id: 9, name: 'Antarctica', code: 'AQ'},
                {id: 10, name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
                {id: 11, name: 'Argentina', code: 'AR'},
                {id: 12, name: 'Armenia', code: 'AM'},
                {id: 13, name: 'Aruba', code: 'AW'},
                {id: 14, name: 'Australia', code: 'AU'},
                {id: 15, name: 'Austria', code: 'AT'},
                {id: 16, name: 'Azerbaijan', code: 'AZ'},
                {id: 17, name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
                {id: 18, name: 'Bahrain', code: 'BH'},
                {id: 19, name: 'Bangladesh', code: 'BD'},
                {id: 20, name: 'Barbados', code: 'BB'},
                {id: 21, name: 'Belarus', code: 'BY'},
                {id: 22, name: 'Belgium', code: 'BE'},
                {id: 23, name: 'Belize', code: 'BZ'},
                {id: 24, name: 'Benin', code: 'BJ'},
                {id: 25, name: 'Bermuda', code: 'BM'},
                {id: 26, name: 'Bhutan', code: 'BT'},
                {id: 27, name: 'Bolivia', code: 'BO'},
                {id: 28, name: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', code: 'BA'},
                {id: 29, name: 'Botswana', code: 'BW'},
                {id: 30, name: 'Bouvet Island', code: 'BV'},
                {id: 31, name: 'Brazil', code: 'BR'},
                {id: 32, name: 'British Indian Ocean Territory', code: 'IO'},
                {id: 33, name: 'Brunei Darussalam', code: 'BN'},
                {id: 34, name: 'Bulgaria', code: 'BG'},
                {id: 35, name: 'Burkina Faso', code: 'BF'},
                {id: 36, name: 'Burundi', code: 'BI'},
                {id: 37, name: 'Cambodia', code: 'KH'},
                {id: 38, name: 'Cameroon', code: 'CM'},
                {id: 39, name: 'Canada', code: 'CA'},
                {id: 40, name: 'Cape Verde', code: 'CV'},
                {id: 41, name: 'Cayman Islands', code: 'KY'},
                {id: 42, name: 'Central African Republic', code: 'CF'},
                {id: 43, name: 'Chad', code: 'TD'},
                {id: 44, name: 'Chile', code: 'CL'},
                {id: 45, name: 'China', code: 'CN'},
                {id: 46, name: 'Christmas Island', code: 'CX'},
                {id: 47, name: 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', code: 'CC'},
                {id: 48, name: 'Colombia', code: 'CO'},
                {id: 49, name: 'Comoros', code: 'KM'},
                {id: 50, name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'},
                {id: 51, name: 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of the', code: 'CD'},
                {id: 52, name: 'Cook Islands', code: 'CK'},
                {id: 53, name: 'Costa Rica', code: 'CR'},
                {id: 54, name: 'Cote D\'Ivoire', code: 'CI'},
                {id: 55, name: 'Croatia', code: 'HR'},
                {id: 56, name: 'Cuba', code: 'CU'},
                {id: 57, name: 'Cyprus', code: 'CY'},
                {id: 58, name: 'Czech Republic', code: 'CZ'},
                {id: 59, name: 'Denmark', code: 'DK'},
                {id: 60, name: 'Djibouti', code: 'DJ'},
                {id: 61, name: 'Dominica', code: 'DM'},
                {id: 62, name: 'Dominican Republic', code: 'DO'},
                {id: 63, name: 'Ecuador', code: 'EC'},
                {id: 64, name: 'Egypt', code: 'EG'},
                {id: 65, name: 'El Salvador', code: 'SV'},
                {id: 66, name: 'Equatorial Guinea', code: 'GQ'},
                {id: 67, name: 'Eritrea', code: 'ER'},
                {id: 68, name: 'Estonia', code: 'EE'},
                {id: 69, name: 'Ethiopia', code: 'ET'},
                {id: 70, name: 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)', code: 'FK'},
                {id: 71, name: 'Faroe Islands', code: 'FO'},
                {id: 72, name: 'Fiji', code: 'FJ'},
                {id: 73, name: 'Finland', code: 'FI'},
                {id: 74, name: 'France', code: 'FR'},
                {id: 75, name: 'French Guiana', code: 'GF'},
                {id: 76, name: 'French Polynesia', code: 'PF'},
                {id: 77, name: 'French Southern Territories', code: 'TF'},
                {id: 78, name: 'Gabon', code: 'GA'},
                {id: 79, name: 'Gambia', code: 'GM'},
                {id: 80, name: 'Georgia', code: 'GE'},
                {id: 81, name: 'Germany', code: 'DE'},
                {id: 82, name: 'Ghana', code: 'GH'},
                {id: 83, name: 'Gibraltar', code: 'GI'},
                {id: 84, name: 'Greece', code: 'GR'},
                {id: 85, name: 'Greenland', code: 'GL'},
                {id: 86, name: 'Grenada', code: 'GD'},
                {id: 87, name: 'Guadeloupe', code: 'GP'},
                {id: 88, name: 'Guam', code: 'GU'},
                {id: 89, name: 'Guatemala', code: 'GT'},
                {id: 90, name: 'Guernsey', code: 'GG'},
                {id: 91, name: 'Guinea', code: 'GN'},
                {id: 92, name: 'Guinea-Bissau', code: 'GW'},
                {id: 93, name: 'Guyana', code: 'GY'},
                {id: 94, name: 'Haiti', code: 'HT'},
                {id: 95, name: 'Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands', code: 'HM'},
                {id: 96, name: 'Holy See (Vatican City State)', code: 'VA'},
                {id: 97, name: 'Honduras', code: 'HN'},
                {id: 98, name: 'Hong Kong', code: 'HK'},
                {id: 99, name: 'Hungary', code: 'HU'},
                {id: 100, name: 'Iceland', code: 'IS'},
                {id: 101, name: 'India', code: 'IN'},
                {id: 102, name: 'Indonesia', code: 'ID'},
                {id: 103, name: 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of', code: 'IR'},
                {id: 104, name: 'Iraq', code: 'IQ'},
                {id: 105, name: 'Ireland', code: 'IE'},
                {id: 106, name: 'Isle of Man', code: 'IM'},
                {id: 107, name: 'Israel', code: 'IL'},
                {id: 108, name: 'Italy', code: 'IT'},
                {id: 109, name: 'Jamaica', code: 'JM'},
                {id: 110, name: 'Japan', code: 'JP'},
                {id: 111, name: 'Jersey', code: 'JE'},
                {id: 112, name: 'Jordan', code: 'JO'},
                {id: 113, name: 'Kazakhstan', code: 'KZ'},
                {id: 114, name: 'Kenya', code: 'KE'},
                {id: 115, name: 'Kiribati', code: 'KI'},
                {id: 116, name: 'Korea, Democratic People\'s Republic of', code: 'KP'},
                {id: 117, name: 'Korea, Republic of', code: 'KR'},
                {id: 118, name: 'Kuwait', code: 'KW'},
                {id: 119, name: 'Kyrgyzstan', code: 'KG'},
                {id: 120, name: 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic', code: 'LA'},
                {id: 121, name: 'Latvia', code: 'LV'},
                {id: 122, name: 'Lebanon', code: 'LB'},
                {id: 123, name: 'Lesotho', code: 'LS'},
                {id: 124, name: 'Liberia', code: 'LR'},
                {id: 125, name: 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', code: 'LY'},
                {id: 126, name: 'Liechtenstein', code: 'LI'},
                {id: 127, name: 'Lithuania', code: 'LT'},
                {id: 128, name: 'Luxembourg', code: 'LU'},
                {id: 129, name: 'Macao', code: 'MO'},
                {id: 130, name: 'Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of', code: 'MK'},
                {id: 131, name: 'Madagascar', code: 'MG'},
                {id: 132, name: 'Malawi', code: 'MW'},
                {id: 133, name: 'Malaysia', code: 'MY'},
                {id: 134, name: 'Maldives', code: 'MV'},
                {id: 135, name: 'Mali', code: 'ML'},
                {id: 136, name: 'Malta', code: 'MT'},
                {id: 137, name: 'Marshall Islands', code: 'MH'},
                {id: 138, name: 'Martinique', code: 'MQ'},
                {id: 139, name: 'Mauritania', code: 'MR'},
                {id: 140, name: 'Mauritius', code: 'MU'},
                {id: 141, name: 'Mayotte', code: 'YT'},
                {id: 142, name: 'Mexico', code: 'MX'},
                {id: 143, name: 'Micronesia, Federated States of', code: 'FM'},
                {id: 144, name: 'Moldova, Republic of', code: 'MD'},
                {id: 145, name: 'Monaco', code: 'MC'},
                {id: 146, name: 'Mongolia', code: 'MN'},
                {id: 147, name: 'Montserrat', code: 'MS'},
                {id: 148, name: 'Morocco', code: 'MA'},
                {id: 149, name: 'Mozambique', code: 'MZ'},
                {id: 150, name: 'Myanmar', code: 'MM'},
                {id: 151, name: 'Namibia', code: 'NA'},
                {id: 152, name: 'Nauru', code: 'NR'},
                {id: 153, name: 'Nepal', code: 'NP'},
                {id: 154, name: 'Netherlands', code: 'NL'},
                {id: 155, name: 'Netherlands Antilles', code: 'AN'},
                {id: 156, name: 'New Caledonia', code: 'NC'},
                {id: 157, name: 'New Zealand', code: 'NZ'},
                {id: 158, name: 'Nicaragua', code: 'NI'},
                {id: 159, name: 'Niger', code: 'NE'},
                {id: 160, name: 'Nigeria', code: 'NG'},
                {id: 161, name: 'Niue', code: 'NU'},
                {id: 162, name: 'Norfolk Island', code: 'NF'},
                {id: 163, name: 'Northern Mariana Islands', code: 'MP'},
                {id: 164, name: 'Norway', code: 'NO'},
                {id: 165, name: 'Oman', code: 'OM'},
                {id: 166, name: 'Pakistan', code: 'PK'},
                {id: 167, name: 'Palau', code: 'PW'},
                {id: 168, name: 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied', code: 'PS'},
                {id: 169, name: 'Panama', code: 'PA'},
                {id: 170, name: 'Papua New Guinea', code: 'PG'},
                {id: 171, name: 'Paraguay', code: 'PY'},
                {id: 172, name: 'Peru', code: 'PE'},
                {id: 173, name: 'Philippines', code: 'PH'},
                {id: 174, name: 'Pitcairn', code: 'PN'},
                {id: 175, name: 'Poland', code: 'PL'},
                {id: 176, name: 'Portugal', code: 'PT'},
                {id: 177, name: 'Puerto Rico', code: 'PR'},
                {id: 178, name: 'Qatar', code: 'QA'},
                {id: 179, name: 'Reunion', code: 'RE'},
                {id: 180, name: 'Romania', code: 'RO'},
                {id: 181, name: 'Russian Federation', code: 'RU'},
                {id: 182, name: 'Rwanda', code: 'RW'},
                {id: 183, name: 'Saint Helena', code: 'SH'},
                {id: 184, name: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', code: 'KN'},
                {id: 185, name: 'Saint Lucia', code: 'LC'},
                {id: 186, name: 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', code: 'PM'},
                {id: 187, name: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', code: 'VC'},
                {id: 188, name: 'Samoa', code: 'WS'},
                {id: 189, name: 'San Marino', code: 'SM'},
                {id: 190, name: 'Sao Tome and Principe', code: 'ST'},
                {id: 191, name: 'Saudi Arabia', code: 'SA'},
                {id: 192, name: 'Senegal', code: 'SN'},
                {id: 193, name: 'Serbia and Montenegro', code: 'CS'},
                {id: 194, name: 'Seychelles', code: 'SC'},
                {id: 195, name: 'Sierra Leone', code: 'SL'},
                {id: 196, name: 'Singapore', code: 'SG'},
                {id: 197, name: 'Slovakia', code: 'SK'},
                {id: 198, name: 'Slovenia', code: 'SI'},
                {id: 199, name: 'Solomon Islands', code: 'SB'},
                {id: 200, name: 'Somalia', code: 'SO'},
                {id: 201, name: 'South Africa', code: 'ZA'},
                {id: 202, name: 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', code: 'GS'},
                {id: 203, name: 'Spain', code: 'ES'},
                {id: 204, name: 'Sri Lanka', code: 'LK'},
                {id: 205, name: 'Sudan', code: 'SD'},
                {id: 206, name: 'Suriname', code: 'SR'},
                {id: 207, name: 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen', code: 'SJ'},
                {id: 208, name: 'Swaziland', code: 'SZ'},
                {id: 209, name: 'Sweden', code: 'SE'},
                {id: 210, name: 'Switzerland', code: 'CH'},
                {id: 211, name: 'Syrian Arab Republic', code: 'SY'},
                {id: 212, name: 'Taiwan, Province of China', code: 'TW'},
                {id: 213, name: 'Tajikistan', code: 'TJ'},
                {id: 214, name: 'Tanzania, United Republic of', code: 'TZ'},
                {id: 215, name: 'Thailand', code: 'TH'},
                {id: 216, name: 'Timor-Leste', code: 'TL'},
                {id: 217, name: 'Togo', code: 'TG'},
                {id: 218, name: 'Tokelau', code: 'TK'},
                {id: 219, name: 'Tonga', code: 'TO'},
                {id: 220, name: 'Trinidad and Tobago', code: 'TT'},
                {id: 221, name: 'Tunisia', code: 'TN'},
                {id: 222, name: 'Turkey', code: 'TR'},
                {id: 223, name: 'Turkmenistan', code: 'TM'},
                {id: 224, name: 'Turks and Caicos Islands', code: 'TC'},
                {id: 225, name: 'Tuvalu', code: 'TV'},
                {id: 226, name: 'Uganda', code: 'UG'},
                {id: 227, name: 'Ukraine', code: 'UA'},
                {id: 228, name: 'United Arab Emirates', code: 'AE'},
                {id: 229, name: 'United Kingdom', code: 'GB'},
                {id: 230, name: 'United States', code: 'US'},
                {id: 231, name: 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', code: 'UM'},
                {id: 232, name: 'Uruguay', code: 'UY'},
                {id: 233, name: 'Uzbekistan', code: 'UZ'},
                {id: 234, name: 'Vanuatu', code: 'VU'},
                {id: 235, name: 'Venezuela', code: 'VE'},
                {id: 236, name: 'Vietnam', code: 'VN'},
                {id: 237, name: 'Virgin Islands, British', code: 'VG'},
                {id: 238, name: 'Virgin Islands, U.S.', code: 'VI'},
                {id: 239, name: 'Wallis and Futuna', code: 'WF'},
                {id: 240, name: 'Western Sahara', code: 'EH'},
                {id: 241, name: 'Yemen', code: 'YE'},
                {id: 242, name: 'Zambia', code: 'ZM'},
                {id: 243, name: 'Zimbabwe', code: 'ZW'}
            ];                     
        }]);            
        app.directive('zcSelect', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    statusVar: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 
                    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.select-head')).bind('click', function(event) {
                        scope.statusVar = !scope.statusVar;
                        scope.$apply();
                        
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    angular.element(document).bind('click', function(event) {
                        if ( scope.statusVar === true ) { 
                            if ( !element.has(angular.element(event.target)) ) {
                                scope.statusVar = !scope.statusVar;
                                scope.$apply();  
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });            
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <zc-select ng-init="CountryOpen = false; Country = []" status-var="CountryOpen">
            <div class="select-head">
                Select a country
            </div>
            <ul class="select-content" ng-show="CountryOpen">
                <li ng-repeat="i in countries" id="{{i.code}}" ng-click="CountryOpen = false">{{i.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </zc-select>
 </body>
</html>
```

somebody know why the ng-click don't work ?

I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. I can't add more details. ( this is for error)

Comment: Can you define "don't work"? you are setting a variable to false, does it not set it to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign to a scope variable in your html template inside an `ng-repeat`. The `ng-repeat` creates a nested scope for each item, so the assignment happens only within that inner scope.

To fix this make sure the name you assign contains at least one dot `.`. An easy way to do this is to switch your code to use the 'controller as' syntax and then you can reference the required controller directly. Another way would simply be to push your scope variables inside an object instead of directly on the scope.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
    <zc-select status-var="vm.CountryOpen">
        <div class="select-head">
            Select a country
        </div>
        <ul class="select-content" ng-show="vm.CountryOpen">
            <li ng-repeat="i in vm.countries" id="{{i.code}}" ng-click="vm.CountryOpen = false">{{i.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </zc-select>
</body>
```

and then update your controller to use `this` instead of `$scope`:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', [function() {
   var vm = this;
   vm.CountryOpen = false;
   vm.Country = [];
   vm.countries = [
   ...
```

(I pushed the ng-init stuff into the controller because it's good to keep as much of the code together as you can and keep the html as clean as possible)

Comment: Thanks! You helped me!